# Reading off energy levels from series expansions of partition functions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, partition-function

I'm having trouble understanding exactly how to approach this practice problem. It seems pretty straight forward but I just don't see the solution.

The canonical partition function $Z(\beta)=\sum_k e^{\beta \cdot \epsilon_k}$ can be rewritten in terms of $x=e^{-\beta \cdot \nu}$, where $\nu$ is a reference energy which may be scaled to better suit a specific system, which gives $Z(x)=\sum_k x^{-\beta \cdot \eta_k}$ with $\eta_k=\epsilon_k/ \nu$. So given $Z(x)$ as a power series in $x$ one may read off the energy states and their respective degeneracy.

a) In QFT the "Chiral Current Algebra" has the partition function $Z(x)=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1-x^n} $. Calculate the energy levels, as well as the degeneracies of the the ground state and the following four excited states.

b) An expansion of the partition function of the Ising Chain as a series in $e^{\beta h}$ and $e^{\beta \nu}$ gave:
[image]
for this exercise let $h=\nu$ and expand $Z(\beta)$ in $x=e^{-\beta \nu}$. From $Z(x)$ read off the degeneracies of the energy eigenvalues $\epsilon_0=-2N\nu$ and $\epsilon_1= \epsilon_0 + 6\nu$ and identify the respective eigen-states (i.e. the respective spin-configurations $|s_1\rangle ⊗ \dots ⊗ |s_N\rangle$).

c) calculate the following two eigen values and their degenaricies for part b) (Hint: this requires you to continue the series expansion for the square root in the approximation).

So part a is the one I'm having the most trouble with. Shouldn't I simply take the dervatice with repect to the $\eta_k$ is require and then evaluate at $x=1$?. For parts b and c I'd like some help finding the eigen-states.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're still interested in this question, but I just stumbled upon it by happenstance. We have
\begin{align} Z &= \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+ x^n + x^{2n} + \dots)  = (1+x + x^2 + \dots) (1+x^2+x^4+\dots)(1+x^3+x^6+\dots)\dots \\&= 1 + x + 2x^2 + 2x^3 + 5x^4 + \dots. \end{align}

If you stare at it long enough, you realize the $n$th coefficient is $p(n)$, the number of partitions of $n$. For example, using the notation $a_n = 1+x^n+x^{2n} + \dots,$ in the final power series we get one $x^4$ from $a_1$ (representing the partition 1+1+1+1), one from $a_2$ (representing 2+2), one from $a_1 a_2$ (1+1+2), one from $a_1 a_3$ (1+3), and one from $a_4$ (4).

Thus, the energies are just $e^{-n\beta \nu},$ $\forall n\ge0,$ with respective degeneracies $p(n)$. In particular, the first few degeneracies are

- ground state: 1
- 1st excited state: 1
- 2nd excited state: 2
- 3rd excited state: 2
- 4th excited state: 5

As for the eigenstates in part (b), the ground state of the (presumably periodic) Ising chain is the configuration where all spins are aligned with the field, $s_i=+1$, which has energy
$$\epsilon_0 = -v \sum_{i=1}^{N} s_i s_{i+1} - h \sum_{i=1}^N s_i = -vN - Nh = -2Nv,$$ where in the last step I've used the condition $h=v$ which was given in the problem.

For the first excited state, we should flip any one of spins, yielding energy
$$\epsilon_1 = 2v -(N-2) v + h - (N-1)h = -(N-4) v - (N-2) h = -(2N -6) v = \epsilon_0 + 6v,$$
with a degeneracy of $N$.